# Question on atomic spin lock and std::this_thread::yield()

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-c++, stl

I've been trying to implement C++ a thread pool with STL that takes in tasks in queues and dispatch the tasks to the threads for execution. The queue uses an atomic spin-lock when pushing and popping, and everything seemed to work well with the following code:

```
void push(const std::function<bool()>& func){
    while(in_use.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acquire));
    //Actually push the queue, deal with possible exceptions, etc.
    in_use.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
}

std::function<bool()> pop(){
    while(in_use.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acquire));
    //Actually push the queue, deal with possible exceptions, etc.
    in_use.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
}
.....//other functions for determining size, etc.
```

Later I decided that std::this_thread::yield may be a good choice in the loop.

(I tanked my PC when I was testing with a task that pushes the same task into the pool, and then polls the pool, when I set the process execution priority to Real-time...)

However, when I changed the line

```
while(in_use.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acquire));
```

to

```
while(in_use.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acquire)) std::this_thread::yield();
```

Under the same condition (task being pushing the same task to the pool, with more tasks than threads in the pool.) with no other modification, all of the threads that pushes into the pool's master queue got blocked in deadlock, all waiting for a variable to be released after running a few minutes.

I was wondering what exactly the yield function can do to an atomic variable operation that could lead to this problem.

PS: CPU hardware: Intel Core i5, OS Windows 10 1803, VS 2017 SDK version 10.0.17763.0.

Comment: Use the mm_pause intrinsic for spin loops. Also, spinning on the result of exchange() is not good for performance.

Comment: @James Thanks for the suggestion. The wait on exchange was actually meant for a replacement for the heavy-weight std::mutex that had better be avoided for simple and frequent tasks (pushing and popping should be simple and frequent enough...), if the wait on exchange were to be changed, what are your suggestions on the replacement? Thanks again! (Although I still want to know why yield does not work, though...)

Comment: You poll on a read, when the condition is satisfied only then do yo do the exchange. If that then fails you go back to polling with a read. Not sure why the sleep is failing

Comment: @James, I was wondering if the compare instruction was cheaper than one write (read always seems more expensive than write?). I came across [this article](https://cbloomrants.blogspot.com/2011/07/07-15-11-review-of-many-mutex.html) the other day which says the opposite for the performance. I was wondering how the difference could be measured, though...